# Regex for finding all aspx links in text files - but not html for replace

Tags: asp.net, regex

I think I'm almost there with the regex, say for example I have the following:

```
<li id="ctl00_dashboard1_liReports" class="fade_hover tooltip" title="Reports">
    <a id="ctl00_dashboard1_HyperLink1" href="reportlist.aspx"><img id="ctl00_dashboard1_imgCheck3" src="assets/icons/dashboard/81.png" alt="Reports" style="border-width:0px;" />
        <span>Reports</span></a></li>
<li id="ctl00_dashboard1_messagetitle" class="fade_hover tooltip" title="8 new alerts">
    <a id="ctl00_dashboard1_messagelink" href="reportlist.aspx?sectionname=My+Tasks"><img id="ctl00_dashboard1_imgCheck4" src="assets/icons/dashboard/75.png" alt="My Tasks" style="border-width:0px;" />
        <span>My Tasks</span></a><span class="bubble">8</span></li>
<li id="ctl00_dashboard1_adminli" class="fade_hover tooltip" title="Admin">
    <a id="ctl00_dashboard1_lnkUser" href="/admin/useradmin.aspx"><img id="ctl00_dashboard1_imgCheck2" src="assets/icons/dashboard/54.png" alt="Admin" style="border-width:0px;" /><span id="ctl00_dashboard1_lbladmin">Admin</span></a></li>
<li id="ctl00_dashboard1_lilogout" class="fade_hover tooltip " title="End current session">
    <a id="ctl00_dashboard1_lnkLogout" href="/default.aspx"><img src="assets/icons/dashboard/118.png" id="ctl00_dashboard1_imgCheck5" alt="Logout" />
        <span>Logout</span></a></li>
```

And i want to replace all the .aspx links after href with a different string. My regex is almost there, but it falls over when the querystring is hit:

```
((&quot;|')[a-z0-9\/\.\?\=\&amp;]*(\.aspx|\.php|\.jsp)[a-z0-9\/\.\?\=\&amp;]*(&quot;|"))|(href=*?[a-z0-9\/\.\?\=\&amp;&quot;"]*)
```

It matches the following, but as you can see stops at the = on the query string. Any help will really be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
href=.*.aspx[0-9a-zA-Z\;\+\=\?\%\&]*
```

Tested on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

**Edit: Edited to include some more special chars and numbers**

Comment: Hey - Thanks for that. Unfortunately it gets stuck on the query string too. Try the URL <a class="loadingbox" href="reporting/dashboard.aspx?dashid=16&amp;stationid=4305"><span class="content center">324</span></a>

Comment: Try again now. I updated to include numbers and some more special chars

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
href=\".*.aspx[^\"]*\"
```

In this regex, we don't need include special chars and numbers as we may miss some.